# Multiple "SELECT DISTINCT" query

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have tried several methods to select multiple columns in a table for unique or distinct data from a table, including queries like:

```
SELECT
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a) FROM TableName),
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b) FROM TableName),
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c) FROM TableName);

SELECT(a, b, c) FROM TableNamegroup by 'a' order by a asc;

SELECT DISTINCT a FROM TableName
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT b FROM TableName
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM TableName;
```

But they either don't work or return the information in a format that I can't use. What I need is a format like this:

```
+--------------------+
| a    | b    | c    |
|--------------------|
| 1    | 1    | 1    |
| 2    | 2    | 2    |
| 3    | 3    | 3    |
   etc......
```

Short of doing individual queries, is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is the source data that corresponds to this desired output?

Comment: Are you querying from the same table three times or multiple tables?

Comment: Why doesn't SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c from TableName work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need three columns, then your `select` needs three columns.  If you want unique combinations:

```
select distinct a, b, c
from TableName;
```

Is this what you want?

I suspect that you want lists of the unique ids in three columns.  You can do this using variables in MySQL:

```
select rn, max(a) as a, max(b) as b, max(c) as c
from ((select @rna := @rna + 1 as rn, a, null as b, null as c
       from (select distinct a from TableName) t cross join
            (select @rna := 0) const
      ) union all
      (select @rnb := @rnb + 1 as rn, null, b, null
       from (select distinct b from TableName) t cross join
            (select @rnb := 0) const
      ) union all
      (select @rnc := @rnc + 1 as rn, null, null, c
       from (select distinct c from TableName) t cross join
            (select @rnc := 0) const
       group by c
      )
     ) abc
group by rn
order by rn;
```

Here is an example of it working in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d50e6/5).

Comment: this query doesn't work , it returns an error: `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: @Ben . . . Which query?  The first one seems pretty basic.

Comment: I was referring to the first, basic query, but I have a feeling new that you were just using that as an example? The second one is exactly what I was looking for, thankyou so much :D

Comment: can you tell me if this query would be very processor intensive with larger data fields? e.g. if each field had excess of 1000 entries? If so, would it be better to break it up then?

Comment: @Ben . . . 1000 values is not very much, unless you are looking for millisecond response times.  The computationally expensive part is the `distinct` for each value in the table, although a separate index on each column would help.